# How to add directions among two custom locations in Mapview for IOS 7 (objective c)

Tags: objective-c, ios7, ios8, mkmapview

I have to add directions among two custom locations in IOS 7.

Any one tell me please.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1.Create a file named ViewController with MKMapView as an IBOutlet and connect the map view from Storyboard to MKMapView property.

[ViewController.h]

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MKAnnotation.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;

@end
```

[ViewController.m]

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "Annotation.h"

#define Location1Latitude -12.429481
#define Location1Longitude 130.863324

#define Location2Latitude -32.15037
#define Location2Longitude 115.782909

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.mapView.delegate = self;

    [self.mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
    [self.mapView setZoomEnabled:YES];
    [self.mapView setScrollEnabled:YES];

    //Annotation
    NSMutableArray * locations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
    Annotation * myAnn;

    // Location 1 Annotation
    myAnn = [[Annotation alloc] init];
    location.latitude = Location1Latitude;
    location.longitude = Location1Longitude;
    [locations addObject:myAnn];

    //Location 2 Annotation
    myAnn = [[Annotation alloc] init];
    location.latitude = Location2Latitude;
    location.longitude = Location2Longitude;
    myAnn.coordinate = location;
    [locations addObject:myAnn];

    [self.mapView addAnnotations:locations];

    [self performSelector:@selector(drawRoute) withObject:self afterDelay:1.0];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)drawRoute {

    MKPlacemark *source = [[MKPlacemark   alloc]initWithCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(Location1Latitude, Location1Longitude) addressDictionary:nil];
    MKMapItem *srcMapItem = [[MKMapItem alloc]initWithPlacemark:source];
    [srcMapItem setName:@"source"];

    MKPlacemark *destination = [[MKPlacemark alloc]initWithCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(Location2Latitude, Location2Longitude) addressDictionary:nil ];
    MKMapItem *destMapItem = [[MKMapItem alloc]initWithPlacemark:destination];
    [destMapItem setName:@"dest"];

    MKDirectionsRequest *request = [[MKDirectionsRequest alloc]init];
    [request setSource:srcMapItem];
    [request setDestination:destMapItem];
    [request setTransportType:MKDirectionsTransportTypeAutomobile];

    MKDirections *direction = [[MKDirections alloc]initWithRequest:request];

    [direction calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler:^(MKDirectionsResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"response = %@ \n eror %@",response, error);

        NSArray *arrRoutes = [response routes];
        [arrRoutes enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

            MKRoute *rout = obj;

            MKPolyline *line = [rout polyline];
            [self.mapView addOverlay:line];
            NSLog(@"Rout Name : %@",rout.name);
            NSLog(@"Total Distance (in Meters) :%f",rout.distance);

            NSArray *steps = [rout steps];

            NSLog(@"Total Steps : %lu",(unsigned long)[steps count]);

            [steps enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
                NSLog(@"Rout Distance : %f",[obj distance]);
                NSLog(@"Rout Instruction : %@",[obj instructions]);
            }];

        }];
    }];

}

- (MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id < MKOverlay >)overlay
{
    MKPolylineRenderer *renderer = [[MKPolylineRenderer alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay];
    renderer.strokeColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:55.0/255.0 green:160.0/255.0 blue:250.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    renderer.lineWidth = 4.0;
    return renderer;
}
```

2.Create a file named Annotation.

[Annotation.h]

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface Annotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation>

@property(nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString * title;
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString * subtitle;
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString * imageName;

@end
```

[Annotation.m]

```
#import "Annotation.h"

@implementation Annotation

@end
```

Comment: thanks for your response. But, when I try this , it will give response = (null). can you tell me?

Comment: Please see my updated answer. And if response = (null) appears, then it means apple does not provide directions service in your country/location. The locations that i have statically added are of Australia.

Comment: yes you are right . apple does not provide directions for the specified location yesterday I added. It works great for ios 7. thanks.)